# Monit fails Jenkins HTTP test when Jenkins is on subdirectory

Tags: monit, jenkins

I am using Monit to monitor all of my services. The Jenkins process fails its HTTP test when Jenkins has the `--prefix=/ci` that I need to run it behind Apache.

1. Is there any way to make Monit search an HTTP subdirectory?
2. Why is it failing on the root because when I visit the root it shows only a 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make monit check a specific HTTP path instead of the default root path.

```
if failed host 127.0.0.1 port 6633 protocol http request '/ci' then restart
```